# How to get the coffeescript working in Play framework 2.3.1?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, playframework-2.3

I am following the "Using Play Framework with scala" tutorial. I am able to follow all the steps except the last one to use the coffeescript with jquery. I can see the javascript file getting generated, but in the browser, I am seeing this error
"ReferenceError: $ is not defined". 
I am new to javascript and coffeescript, 
here is my coffeescript code:

[image: main.coffee]

and here is the javascript as shown in the browser console
[image: Generated Java Script]

is there some syntax issue that can cause the problem? Help appreciated.
I am attaching the image, if indentation could be one of the reasons for this to fail.

Comment: You do understand `$` is for the jQuery library, right? Did you include jQuery on your page? `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` says it's not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

basic javascript, now everything seems crystal clear.

Just one line to include jquery in the index.scala.html to include jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

add this line (depending on your version of jQuery)

`<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.11.2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

to the `<head> </head>` section in `app/views/main.scala.html` .

For me, this template is loading for every page. but first you need to download jQuery and add it to your javascripts folder (under public).

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2.3: Note the `lib/jquery/jquery.js` path. The `lib` folder denotes the extract WebJar assets, the `jquery` folder corresponds to the WebJar artifactId, and the `jquery.js` refers to the required asset at the root of the WebJar.

So just add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Assets.versioned("lib/jquery/jquery.js")"></script>
```

to the `<head> </head>` section in `app/views/main.scala.html`.